# Unable to serialize com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Tables

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Bigquery,Tables to make a request to fetch the schema of a bigquery table from inside DoFn by passing a initialised tableRequest as a parameter as shown below

```
private static class FetchSchema extends DoFn<String,List<String>>{
    Bigquery.Tables tableRequest;
    ValueProvider<String> DestTableName;
    ValueProvider<String> mapCols;
    ValueProvider<String> recATableName;

    public FetchSchema(Bigquery.Tables tableReq,ValueProvider<String> table,ValueProvider<String> mCols,ValueProvider<String> recATab){
        this.tableRequest = tableReq;
        this.DestTableName = table;
        this.mapCols = mCols;
        this.recATableName = recATab;
    }
    private List<String> getTableParams(String tableString) throws IOException{
        String[] tableParams = new String[3];
        List<String> tableParamsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        tableParams[0] = tableString.substring(0,tableString.indexOf(":"));
        tableParams[1] = tableString.substring(tableString.indexOf(":")+1,tableString.indexOf("."));
        tableParams[2] = tableString.substring(tableString.indexOf("."));
        Table table = tableRequest.get(tableParams[0],tableParams[1],tableParams[2]).execute();
        List<TableFieldSchema> fields = table.getSchema().getFields();
        for(int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++){
            tableParamsList.add(fields.get(i).getName());
            tableParamsList.add(fields.get(i).getDescription());
        }
        return tableParamsList;
    }
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException{
        String[] mCols = mapCols.get().split(",");
        List<String> mapColsList = Arrays.asList(mCols);
        c.output(getTableParams(DestTableName.get()));
        c.output(getTableParams(recATableName.get()));
        c.output(mapColsList);
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: unable to serialize org.apache.beam.examples.flatFileTest$FetchSchema@6510b00e: com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Tables
```

Any help please?

Comment: The error says that the class `BigQuery.Tables` is not `Serializable`, and that is true: it indeed is not. Fields of a DoFn need to be serialized to ship the DoFn to the workers. Why do you need to pass an instance of `BigQuery.Tables` to the DoFn: can you create it in the DoFn itself?

Comment: `Bigquery bigQueryClient = newBigQueryClient(options.as(BigQueryOptions.class)).build();`

`Bigquery.Tables tableRequest = bigQueryClient.tables();`
I use the above lines in main function to initialise the instance. I can't do it in DoFn itself coz options is not available outside main function or maybe I'm wrong if there's other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BigQuery client created on your local machine is not useful to all of the workers used to execute your pipeline using Dataflow. Instead, you should create the `BigQuery.Tables` client within the `@StartBundle` method of your DoFn. This method can take a `StartBundleContext` argument, which allows calling `getPipelineOptions()`.

Note: Ideally this would be possible `@Setup` method so the client could be reused across bundles, but it doesn't seem like the pipeline options are available there.